# SQL Server database : compare differences detected on UserType

Tags: sql-server

While updating the production database some changes kept coming back. I did not know why, they seemed to be exactly the same. Just now, I figured out that there is a dropdown with extra properties, see the screenshot below.

[image: SQL Compare output]

There is a difference for the 3 user objects.

[image: Difference in UserType]

Ok, so the difference is in the UserType. I could not find documentation on this UserType.

What does this property represent?

And how can I get rid of this difference between the source code and database?

Comment: Try generating the script for the change and view the DDL. I suspect the compare is showing an enum value.

Comment: The generated script does not modify the users or their properties.

Comment: It looks like the UserType property is of type [ModelPropertyClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.user.usertype?view=sql-dacfx-160). I believe the property value may vary depending on the source and target model properties (e.g. EngineVersion). Are the differences in source/target versions/platforms? In this case, it seems the diff is a no-op from a schema update perspective.

Comment: The comparison is done between a database project in VS 2022 & an Azure SQL Database. Both compatibility level set at 150.

Comparing between the pre-prod and prod databases does not show these differences.  So it is probably platform related. Is the UserType related to this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.usertype?view=sql-smo-150

Comment: @What is the target platform of the database project? Yes, it could be the SMO enum value.

Comment: The target platform is Microsoft Azure SQL Database.